# How to fix the gap in the list?

Tags: java, arraylist

The ensureCapacitymethod creates more space in a list so that more elements can be added to the list. The problem with the method is that it potentially creates a gap in the list. How can I fix that gap?

```
public class UnboundedList<K extends Comparable<K>,V> extends SimpleBoundedList<K,V> {

    public UnboundedList(int bound) {
        super(bound);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(K key, V value) {
        ensureCapacity();
        super.add(key, value);

        return true;
    }

    private void ensureCapacity() {
        if (this.size() == this.values.length) {
            Object[] newArray = new Object[values.length * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            newArray[i] = values[i];
        }

        this.values = newArray;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: What actual problem are you having? What is it you need to "fix"?

Comment: The ensureCapacity method is broken. It potentially creates a gap in the list. I need to fix that gap. I don't know how I can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make sure that the size of your list will be able to compensate for the added values *before* they've been added.

```
public final void onEnsureCapacity(final Object[] pObjects) {
     if((this.getSize() + pObjects.length) > this.getValues().length) {
          /* Resize to accommodate. */
     }
}
```

What this code does is checks that if the current 'virtual' size of the list plus the size of the array to add to the list is greater than the current size, we must choose a size of the array which will accommodate for both.

Comment: In my code, I increase the size of the array, but why does it create a potential gap?

Comment: I don't believe that it would, unless you are sharing the object across multiple threads and are experiencing a race condition...

Upon closer inspection, it doesn't seem to accommodate for the case where you try to add a number of values to the list that exceeds twice the current size.

Comment: Further to this, you only add to the list when the size is equal to the data you intend to add (I presume, it's hard to tell from the provided code sections).

Comment: I'd suggest reading through the logic used here as a guide.
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org$maven2@com.badlogicgames.gdx$gdx@1.4.0@com$badlogic$gdx$utils$FloatArray.java